# Prove that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $(0,\frac{1} {n}) = \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis

I know the Nested Interval Property states that closed intervals are necessary for there to be some $x \in \mathbb{R}: a_{n} \leq x \leq b_{n}$.

I can see how this being a closed interval means that $inf$ $A_{n}$ is $0$, however $0$ is not included in the interval. However, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\dfrac {1} {n} \rightarrow 0$. Since $0$ is not in the interval, that only possible intersection is excluded, and thus $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}=\emptyset$.

Am I understanding this correctly, and is there a better way for me to state it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you got the point.

If $x$ is in the intersection, then $0<x<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. 
What does the right-hand side inequality imply? You get $0<x\leq 0$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, you can find an interval $(0, \frac{1}{n})$ that does not contain $x$.

One simple choice is $\left(0, \frac{1}{\lceil x \rceil}\right)$.

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists I \in \{ (0,\frac{1}{n}): n \in \mathbb{N} \}: x \notin I \iff \\
\iff \nexists x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall I \in \{ (0,\frac{1}{n}): n \in \mathbb{N} \}: x \in I \iff \\
\iff \nexists x \in \mathbb{R}: x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (0,\frac{1}{n})\iff \\
\iff \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (0,\frac{1}{n}) = \varnothing. $$